# Getting a weird pointer error, though not using pointers

Tags: c

I've wrote a program that gets a string, and then calculate a total value of the string togheder...
For Example :

```
char data[256] = "1$0.83331333333333334$false$false"; // the data
```

Here I need to do the calculation of 1 + 0.83331333333333334
so this is what I wrote:

```
char data[256] = "1$0.83331333333333334$false$false"; // the data
double grade = 0;
int i = 0;
int times = 0;
char temp[256] = "";

int flag = 0;

while (flag == 0)
{
      times = 0;

      if (isdigit(data[i])) // if it's a number
      {
                           if (data[i + 1] == '.') // if it's a double number
                           {
                                      i = i + 2;
                              while (isdigit(data[i])) // putting it into a temp array
                              {
                                  temp[i] = data[i];
                                  i++;
                                  times++;
                              }
                              grade = grade + (double)temp / (times * 10);
                           }
                           grade = grade + (int)data[i]; // if it's an int number, putting it into grade right away
      }

      if (data[i] == '\0')
      {
                  flag = 1;
      }

      i++;
}

printf ("%f\n", grade);
```

the problem is in the line :

```
grade = grade + (double)temp / (times * 10);
```

it says "pointer value used where a floating point value was expected".
I really couldent understand whats the problem...

Thanks :)

Edit:

Thanks for your help!
I've been able to convert the number into a string..
so for example, now if I have the big string in data, with couple of doubles inside it, I can take in a loop every time the double into a new string.
I've used atof to convert it into a double, though it seems that the double is too small..
For example :
I have in the string temp : "83331333333333334", and I used atof on it -> the new double has 8333313 only... the rest is like not going into the double..
I guess that the number is too big for a double number... so what Can I do ?
Thanks!

Comment: temp is a char* and you are casting to double

Comment: I know, thats what I was trying to do.. ?

Comment: You maybe wanted a _conversion_, as @ouah suggested

Comment: @AmitM9S6 What do you want casting a char* to a double to do ?

Comment: The new question is a new question. Ask it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply cast a `char` array to `double` and expect the compiler to treat it as a `double`. You need to convert `temp` via a suitable function such as `strtod` and then use that value in your calculations.

Note that `strod` requires a C-style string i.e. null-terminated character array. So, passing in `temp` is not enough. You need to null terminate `temp` i.e. once you are done inserting the digits, add an `temp[ i ] = 0;`.

Here's a little program that will probably help you fix your errors and help you use `strtod`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 char data[256] = "1$0.83331333333333334$false$false"; // the data
 char *p = strtok( &data[ 0 ], "$" ); 
 while (p) {
    double d = strtod( p, NULL );
    printf( "extracted value = %.10f\n", d );
    p = strtok( NULL, "$" );
 }
}
```

Since the OP wanted something simpler than `strtod`:

You can use `double atof(const char *nptr);`. In my sample source replace the `strtod( p, NULL );` by `atof( p );` and that should get you started. The problem with `atof` and friends is that error handling is difficult and if the value cannot be represented you silently invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: I've added an temp[i + 1] = 0 (because the last temp[i] has a number), though it stll gives me zero....

Comment: @AmitM9S6: I've added a snippet that may help you understand how strings are tokenized (typically in C) and how to use `strtod`. Note that `strtok` has a few issues (e.g. is not thread-safe) so you will probably not want to use it in production code.

Comment: I didnt really understand what u did there.. isnt strtok simply converting string into a double.. ? so I can use it like temp_num = strtod(temp, NULL); ?

Comment: No, `strtok` tokenizes i.e. breaks up the input string (first argument) based on the value of the second (here we have specified only one delimite i.e. `$`). It returns a pointer to a C-style string to the first such delimited string at first (which is what we store in `p` and test for non-null). If it is a valid string, we print it and ask `strtok` for more. `strtok` has an internal static buffer (this is where thread safety goes haywire) where it keeps a copy of the original string you had sent so you no longer need to specify it again (and thus you send `NULL`) and another set of delimiters

Comment: Potentially, you can keep the delimiter set the same, as I've. Also, as and when we get a valid C-string we convert it to a `double` using `strtod`. Note that `strtod` also converts the string `"false"` to `0`!

Comment: Is there a way to simply convert string to a double ? this strtod is really complicated for me..

Comment: You can use `double atof(const char *nptr);`. In my sample source replace the `strtod( p, NULL );` by `atof( p );` and that should get you started. The problem with `atof` and friends is that error handling is difficult and if the value cannot be represented you silently invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`temp` is an array and when evaluated in an expression it is converted to a pointer to its first element. Use `strtod` to convert the string to a `double`.

Comment: I'm trying to show what I've wrote, though I have no idea how to write a code in a comment... the ` code ` doesnt seems to be working to me... anyway, using the strtod, it gave me the double number as 0.000, while when I've printed the numbers going into temp[i], it gave the exact double number...